# Which way of winding the toroid ferrite ring is correct?

Tags: ferrite, toroidal

Following my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/410555/how-to-interpret-the-vertical-axis-of-this-attenuation-plot) I'm trying to prepare a test to see the effect of a [torodial ferrite ring](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/12a6/0900766b812a6654.pdf). The setup will be simply as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAY1gJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But I'm not sure which way the wires should be wound around the toroid.

Which one below is correct:

Photo 1(wires wound together):
[image: Photo 1]

Photo 2(separately wound):
[image: Photo 2]

I want to vary the sine wave of the function generator from 1MHz upto 10MegHz and observe the attenuation on scope. If the setup is fine, which way of winding if correct? Photo 1 or Photo 2?

Answer (score 3):

Picture 1 shows the winding for a common mode filter. This will attenuate the sum of the current flowing on the wires. This is useful when something like a PC is sending RF along the mains lead or a USB lead. It will not attenuate differential signals.

Picture 2 shows the winding for a differential mode filter. This will attenute your signal. However, it won't attenuate it very much, as the scope load is so high. The resistive part of the load is 680k, which might as well be infinity compared to 70 ohms.

You've not defined the capacitive part of the scope load. Depending on what you mean by 'scope probe', it could be a few pFs, if it's a good 10:1 probe, it could be around 30pF if it's the basic scope input, it could be 100pF or more if you have a length of 50ohm coax connected to the scope. This is what will cause signal attenuation at high frequencies.

Comment: If I add a 3.3u capacitor between the node A and B, would that form a LP filter for differential mode or common mode case? Because in real the load will be a capacitor(1u or 3.3u) followed by a DC-DC converter.

Comment: I understand now I think what you mean. For differential mode 3.3uF becomes 0.05 Ohm. I can add a 100 Ohm resistor for differential attenuation. But for common mode I will use Picture1. Should I use two probes to see CM attenuation and subtract the channels(hot and gnd) on scope?

Comment: To measure CM attenuation, twist A and B together, and the two terminals that go to the function generator together, and measure the attenuation of the two wires in parallel. Obviously you will need to lift the ground at B, and use a different ground path. Doing meaningful things with the grounds, understanding what you've done, what effect it has on measurements, and whether that's the right thing to do, are some of the problems with trying to make CM measurements in a single-ended (one terminal grounded) circuit.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean can you provide a diagram for such test?otherwise I can ask as a separate question.

Comment: And here the CM choke the wires are not wound together https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN008 Look at Figure 2 there it says common mode even the wires are seperately wound.

Comment: Please see my new question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/410722/is-this-setup-proper-to-observe-the-attenuation-effect-of-a-common-mode-choke I'm trying to make a setup to see the attenuation with and without the choke.

Answer (score 0):

From your schematic, it appears that you are using the toroid to form a common mode choke. While the first picture shows the correct winding direction, the pairs should not be twisted while winding around the core. Instead, they should be wound in a bifilar fashion as shown below. However, unlike this picture below from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bifilar_wound_toroidal_transformer.jpg), do not overlap the final bifilar turns.

[image]

Comment: Are there other type of CM ferrite that one doesnt need to wound?

Comment: There are split cores that are snapped onto the wires. This is typically equivalent to a single winding in a toroid. You may be familiar with this type of core as they are often on computer cables.

Comment: If I add two in series, is that equivalent to two rounds?

Comment: Yes assuming the basically the same ferrite material and core dimensions. Sometimes the hole in the split core is large enough that you can make a few windings before closing up the core. You can combine the two techniques as well.

Comment: Thanks if I use something like this https://media.rs-online.com/t_large/F1232486-01.jpg, is that fine if the wires are twisted(plus and ground wires as in my diagram)?

Comment: That will not be a problem.

Comment: Common mode wiring shown very different here https://www.coilcraft.com/cmc/index.cfm than  in my Photo 1. What do you think?

Comment: @cm64 That style is suitable for DC and low frequency AC. The style shown in my answer maintains transmission line properties for RF circuits.

Comment: In my case I want to suppress 1MegHz  to 5Meg Hz and want to use it at the output of SMPS DC power supply like the wires as in my photo. Which type of wiring do you recommend`? I opened another question related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/410722/is-this-setup-proper-to-observe-the-attenuation-effect-of-a-common-mode-choke